# Windows Server 200 8 R2 install without Mouse or Keyboard

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2

Will a Windows Server 2008 R2 installation go through all the installation steps without a keyboard or mouse hooked up to the server? These are Dell R610 servers and I believe they will startup without a keyboard or mouse.

I want to be able to hookup a keyboard just to select a PXE boot of an unattended install and then move onto the next one, and I don't have a kvm, yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can supply (f.e. on a USB stick, or in a custom installation image) a `unattend.xml` file configured for a fully unattended setup, yes, it will.

But it can be somewhat tricky to get it to work properly and in a fully unattended mode.

Comment: Got it working for VM clients so hopefully it works on the metal as well.  That part wouldn't have really been that hard if all the fields for the first stage that are actually required were documented...    I will try to get that out there for everyone...